# Return file name with laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, file

I want to return the files names of a dir called `public/uploads`. I used `Storage::allFiles` and `Storage::files`, but only return an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Storage` works only for storage directory. If you want to use it, you'll need to create a symbolic link.

Use `File` facade instead:

```
File::files(public_path('uploads'));
```